# How to store random class variable in way that can be accessed from other methods in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, oop, typed

I need to get a random class, store in to a "global class" variable (so i can access it in other methods), but i cannot find any good way to do it, what i've been trying to do is work with object variables... I'm coming from python to c#, so the properties of object variables looks kind of a mystery to me... I have been searching how to make it work, but i could not find a proper way to do it without a bunch of if statements...

```
//There might not be all the necessary namespaces to run this code
using UnityEngine; //where the random.range() came from

public class man1 //Initialization of the first class
{
    public int val = 1;
}

public class man2 //Initialization of the second class
{
    public int val = 2;
}

public class man3 //Initialization of the third class
{
    public int val = 3;
}

public class allMan
{ //Where all classes 'merge'

    private object chosenMan; //Where the chosen it's going to be stored

    public allMan() //Constructor
    {
        //Have all man in one array to easily get the chosen from index
        object[] men = new object[] { new man1(), new man2(), new man3() }; 
        var choice = Random.range(0, men.Length); //Randomly get the index
        chosenMan = men[choice]; // Atribute the chosen class
    }
    public void doActionWithChoosedMan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chosenMan.val); //ERROR
    }
}
```

How should i approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Class man1, man2 and man3 does not give enough details of why you may be doing this. Do you mind using another example of man1, 2 and 3 that does something similar to what you actually want, showing why you are doing this?

Comment: You may just have a very poor example. But if all the class share common traits then create a base class to represent the common traits and have all the classes derive from the common base class. You would then have the chosen object as the base class type.

Comment: Try following anonymous definition  : var men =  new { man1 = new man1(), man2 = new man2(), man3 = new man3() };

Comment: Its a (pseudo) Random number generator, so why cant you create as manay as you like where ever you need them?  The output wont change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One variable is typed as object by the compiler and all instance members will be verified as valid by the compiler. The other variable is typed as dynamic and all instance members will be ignored by the compiler and called by the DLR at execution time.

You can use `dynamic` instead of `object`

```
 public class allMan
   { 
    //Where all classes 'merge'

    private dynamic chosenMan; //Where the chosen it's going to be stored

    public allMan() //Constructor
    {
        //Have all man in one array to easily get the chosen from index
        object[] men = new object[] { new man1(), new man2(), new man3() };
        var choice = Random.range(0, men.Length); //Randomly get the index
        chosenMan = men[choice]; // Atribute the chosen class
    }
    public void doActionWithChoosedMan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chosenMan.val); //ERROR
    }
}
```

Comment: @OP if you go with this, please note that this is typically not a great C# practice to do this

Comment: Why would it be bad?

Comment: Using dynamic also adds little work for run time, and you will not get advantage of type checking at compilation time. When it can be done using inheritance/interface (as per Zaitsman answer), then why to use dynamic?

Comment: @KaiqueSantos dynamic is bad practice (apart from things mentioned by CreativeManix) because it tells whoever reads your code that you didn't know what type this object is going to have. Whereas simply by reading your code they can see that it was known at compile time. The idea of compiled languages is usually to try to catch any errors when developing, not running the code. (reason being, it is likely users who run the code, not developers)

Answer (score 3):

While @programtreasures posts a good immediate solution, you need to consider that C# is a strongly typed language. That means that, unlike python and javascript, you can't attempt to randomly access undeclared properties and methods on an object.

Note that in the case you've demonstrated, there is no difference across your 3 classes. They should simply be instances of a type `Man`, like so

```
class Man 
{
 public int Val { get; set; } // try to use properties to hold externally accessible values
}

public class AllMan // c# uses Pascal casing
{ //Where all classes 'merge'

    private Man chosenMan; //Where the chosen it's going to be stored

    public AllMan() //Constructor
    {
        //Have all man in one array to easily get the chosen from index
        var men = new Man[] { new Man() { Val = 1 }, new Man() { Val = 2 }, new Man() { Val = 3 } }; 
        var choice = Random.range(0, men.Length); //Randomly get the index
        chosenMan = men[choice]; // Atribute the chosen class
    }

    public void DoActionWithChoosedMan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chosenMan.Val);
    }
}
```

For something that requires you to have differences on types, you could declare an interface, e.g.

```
interface IMan
{
int Val {get;}
}
```

And then have your different types implement this:

```
class Man1 : IMan
{
public int Val {get;} = 1;
public string SomethingElse {get;set;}
}

class Man2 : IMan
{
public int Val {get;} = 2;
public boolean AmICool {get;set;}
}
```

Then you could run the code as above, but changing the type of `chosenMan` field to be `IMan`.

Additionally, you might also want to implement an `abstract` base class to hold just the property you require and then stack the rest of things on top. That depends on whether the default initialization is shared across classes and whether there is anything else common that requires an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
In doActionWithChoosedMan() method you are directly using the chosenMan but it is not the correct way of doing.

before using it you have to check the type of the chosenMan
by

```
if(chosenMan.GetType() == typeof(man1)){
            man1 man11= new man1();
            Console.WriteLine(man11.val); //No Error
}if(chosenMan.GetType() == typeof(man2)){
            man1 man22= new man1();
            Console.WriteLine(man22.val); //No Error
}if(chosenMan.GetType() == typeof(man3)){
            man1 man33= new man1();
            Console.WriteLine(man33.val); //No Error
}
```

Same way you have to check for all the object then create the object of the main class which is here "man1" and then you will be able to access the "val".

**Solution 2:** You can make chosenMan dynamic.

Comment: I don't understand what this accomplishes? All cases do the exact same thing. The code can all be reduced to `Console.WriteLine(new man1().val);` Also, you might want to use `else if` to avoid unnecessary comparisons.